# Group data based on certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, group-by

I have a table called x, the table has id column and repeat status column. The id can store same values even 6 of them while the repeat status increments each time an id is inserted 1,2...n. If a new different id is inserted the repeat status starts from 1 e.g

```
 xid       repeat_status
xx123           1
xx123           1
xx123           2
xx123           3
xx123           3 
xxx45           1
xxx45           2
xxx45           2
```

How can I modify the query below to return something like this:

```
 xid           repeat_status
xx123             1
xx123             2
xx123             3

xxx45             1
xxx45             2

SELECT xid
      ,repeat_status 
FROM x 
GROUP BY repeat_status;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also try group by query like this

```
SELECT xid, repeat_status FROM x 

GROUP BY xid,repeat_status
```

Post : [**What is difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY?**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/)

**A DISTINCT and GROUP BY usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs.**

but this is for **sql server** not have idea bout **mysql**

Comment: is this one faster than mine on a huge dataset>?

Comment: i'm going to investigate what happens at the ASM level to the sortnig

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - in sql server it doesnt make any difference that i edited in my answer..

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct xid, repeat_status
from x
order by xid, repeat_status
```

Comment: I have tried the above but it has not worked, the values 1, 2 can to 10. They vary per xid

Comment: i've edited, check again